# "Petrol aggregate"?

Tags: meaning-in-context

Can anybody help me with the following passage?

> Eigner and his deputy, Mustafa Riza Tadjadod, were to come down out
>   of the hills to the railway and plant time fuses at irregular intervals
>   along the line, thus wrecking it in several different places. Results were
>   to be reported to Abwehr II by means of a tiny, briefcase-sized W/T set
>   with **petrol aggregate** (Model SE 100/5).

The text is about sabotage operation of the Nazi Regime in Persia during World War II. The meaning of "petrol aggregate" in this context is ambiguous for me. Does it refer to the fuel used for this W/t set (wireless transmitter)?

Comment: I would presume it's "tar" or "asphalt".

Comment: Did they put something in the petrol? That would sabotage.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey so the intent is really something like "...tiny, briefcase-sized wireless transmitter set with gas-powered generator"?

Comment: I would avoid "gas-powered" because, in American English "gas" could be "gasoline" (petrol, petroleum spirit) but in other varieties of English, "gas-powered" would make people think of a real gas, like butane, LPG, hydrogen, etc.

Comment: Exactly as Michael Harvey said -  in some languages _aggregate_ is synonymous to _generator_, but not in English.

Comment: "Generating set" ("gen-set") conveys the idea of an amalgamation of an engine and a dynamo or alternator. Cf _groupe électrogène_ in French.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most probably it refers to a portable power station (petrol-powered electricity generator) to power the radio. Check and compare the links below:

[petrol aggregate](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22petrol%20aggregate%22&client=firefox-b-d&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjF2cOvxqPkAhUMlYsKHUBuDw8Q_AUIEigC&biw=1280&bih=888)

[W/T set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_British_Army_radio_sets)

[contemporary petrol-powered electricity generators](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22petrol%20powered%20electricity%20generator%22&client=firefox-b-d&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjIh9HkxqPkAhVCxosKHRVLANcQ_AUIEygD&biw=1280&bih=888)

Answer (score 5):

"*Petrol-aggregat*" is in a number of Nordic languages and "*petrol aggregate*" in German, meaning "petrol (or gasoline) generating set". The set is an engine and electric generator combined ("aggregated") together. The use of "*aggregate*" in the English translation is an **error**.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey - Since that idea was put forward by you, you deserve to have credit for it.

Comment: I was too cowardly to post it as an answer; you deserve the credit, in my opinion.

Comment: Good answer.  That is why this "petrol aggregate" has a model number.  (Unlike tar or asphalt, which "petrol aggregate" might mean in English.)  This is just a bad translation of German to English.

Comment: There is no German word "petrol aggregate". The closest term for a gasoline-powered portable generator would be "Stromaggregat" (e.g. see the [German Wikipedia](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stromerzeugungsaggregat)).

Comment: The distinction also exists in English, but it's entirely technical. If you ask someone who works with them, a device that converts motion into electricity is a *generator*, and a device that combines a generator with a motor to turn it is a *genset*. A gasoline powered portable generator is the latter.